# Adding a Inner Join Update statement to an SQLdatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I've got a Gridview connected to an sqldatasource connected to sqlserver, I have added the `Select` statement to be this, and it works like i want it.

```
SELECT S.[ID], S.[Survey_Name], S.[Start_Date], S.[End_Date], C.[Category_Name], S.[Username], S.[Picture],S.[Audience] FROM [Survey] S
Inner Join
Category C On S.Category_ID = C.ID
```

I now need to add an `Update` statement to just update the fields above when the user tries to edit the gridview, I tried this:

```
UPDATE 
         Survey S
INNER JOIN
         Category C
                  On S.Category_ID = C.ID
 SET
 S.Survey_Name=@Survey_Name,
S.Start_Date=@Start_Date,
S.End_Date = @End_Date, 
C.Category_Name =@Category_Name,
S.Username = @Username,
S.Audience=@Audience 

Where
 ID=@ID
```

But it just wont work, and keeps giving me errors like Invalid syntax "S", or Invalid Syntax "Inner"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your update statement is incorrect:

```
UPDATE Survey
 SET
 Survey.Survey_Name=@Survey_Name,
 Survey.Start_Date=@Start_Date,
 Survey.End_Date = @End_Date, 
 C.Category_Name = @Category_Name,
 Survey.Username = @Username,
 Survey.Audience=@Audience 
FROM Survey S
INNER JOIN Category C 
 On S.Category_ID = C.ID
Where
 S.ID=@ID
```

**EDIT**

```
UPDATE Survey
 SET
 Survey_Name=@Survey_Name,
 Start_Date=@Start_Date,
 End_Date = @End_Date, 
 Category_ID =C.ID,
 Username = @Username,
 Audience=@Audience 
FROM Survey S
INNER JOIN Category C 
 On C.Category_Name = @Category_Name
WHERE
 S.ID=@ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I tried it, but when I updated it gave me "Ambiguous column name 'ID'", I'm guessing its because Category & Survey both have a primary key called "ID", the category_ID in survey is a foreign key of category's Primary key. how do i fix this?

Comment: In your where clause change it to `C.ID=@ID` or `S.ID=@ID`, whichever is correct.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, thanks, but it didnt work, gives me "The multi-part identifier "C.Category_Name" could not be bound."

Comment: @whosrdaddy, but i only want to change which category that survey belongs to (imagine i have a dropdownbox in the edit template of category_name to which the values are fixed), why do i need to update the category table?

Comment: @BasharKH Yeah I realized this now, you should update the CategoryID field of the survey table not the category_name field of the category table. I updated my answer

Comment: One last question if u dont mind, If i was to put a drop down list in the edit template of the category name column in this gridview, how can i make it so the items are the values of the category_name in the Category table? instead of adding them as items.

Comment: @BasharKH: please post that as a new question :) You can always refer back to this question.